# creating 2D-array in column major

Tags: mips, multidimensional-array

Prompt for and get the number of rows, then the number of columns, then the integer values for each position in the 2D array.  Store them in column-major order.To get an array of integer numbers from the user, using keyboard input terminal output, means prompting for and getting the following information: # of rows, # of columns, R0 C0 value, R0 C1 value, etc till all values have been entered

Comment: What is the question? And what have you tried?

Comment: I should write a program in mips assembly language.the program should create 2D array the user should specify its row and column number. It shoul be column major. I couldn't make meaningful tries.